# GroupHeaderTpl: Get row value for a specific column in ExtJs grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to find pattern to get the first value of specific column so that I can include in Group Header

groupHeaderTpl: ['{columnName}: {name} ({children.length}) ']

Grid is grouped by Number, I want to show Name[0] for each group on header

[image]

Comment: Well, `{children}` seems to be an array, and by the name I guess it is a list of records. Have you tried what happens when you output `{children[0].Name}` or `{children[0].data.Name}`?

Comment: Din't work. it gave me literal string.